# sqlalchemy how to query using 2 conditions

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to query a database table with more than one condition. Is it possible to write a query such as:

```
Table.query.filter_by(id=1, forename='Jake').first()
```

And if not, how would I write a query that would return a data where both the id=1 and the forename='Jake'.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=filter_by#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter_by

Answer (score 0):

You can use .filter as well: `Table.query.filter(Table.id==1, Table.forename=='Jake').first()`.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=filter_by#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter